# Does Auto Loader process the file again when the file gets appended or overwritten?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, dataverse, databricks-autoloader

I have the case where data owner has enabled some extra columns in D365 this week. for example I had a table with 5 columns last week but starting from this week I have extra 6th column in that specific table.

Problem is that I dont know how the [Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse ( append only mode)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-advanced-configuration) acts in that case. Main question is will it resend all the files ( with updated 6th column) again that has already  been processed by autoloader or it will overwrite old files.

If it will overwrite old file then I have a probem that autolaoder will never ever read those files again sice Im using file notification mode.

My main question is, is there a way that I can tell autolaoder that if there has been some modification (overwrite or append) on old files, it will still pick them up and act on it?

I saw this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/auto-loader/faq#--does-auto-loader-process-the-file-again-when-the-file-gets-appended-or-overwritten) but did not really help to understand

Comment: What is not clear with the doc? It says that there could be an edge case when the same data could be processed more than once. So you'll need to have some logic to handle duplicate ingestions...